# python-wxgtk2.8 for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to step up Plover stenographic keyboard in my Ubuntu. There is only the package *python-wxgtk3.0* in *apt-get*. The layout is only for Python 2.7. The system has Python 2.7 but for some reason 3.0 package of the wxgtk in the *apt-get*.

How can you install python-wxgtk2.8 in Ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the bottom of the page [here](https://github.com/openstenoproject/plover/releases/tag/v3.0.0). The version 3.0 uses python 2.7.
So it is sufficient for Ubuntu 16.04 (Python 2.7.11+) and 14.04.